# Remove triplet items from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I do want to remove the numbers that appears (03) times from my array. I don't want to remove duplicates because it will still leave the numbers I don't want. The repetitive numbers are 143 & 187.

```
var number = [11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 143, 143, 143, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 187, 187, 187, 191];
for (i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    if ((number[i] == number[i + 1]) && (number[i + 1] == number[i + 2])) {
        document.write(number[i]);
        document.write(number[i + 1]);
        document.write(number[i + 2] + "<br>");
        number.splice(number[i - 1], number[i], number[i + 1], number[i + 2]);
    }
};
document.write(number);
```

Comment: @Rejith R Krishnan  I don't want to use unique value from duplicate. I want to remove all numbers that repeats 2 or 3 times.

Comment: what about `3+` occurrences?

Comment: that can work too! but I said 3times because I figure out that the ones I wanted to remove occur 3 times.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Take a look.

Comment: That one works! Thx Buddy

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried it like the following. You can remove `3` or more consecutive occurrences using the following.

```js
var number = [11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 143, 143, 143, 143, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 187, 187, 187, 191];
var prev;
var occurance = 1;
var deletePos = [];
var offset = 0;
/* Get 3+ repeat positions. */
for(i = 0; i < number.length; i++){
  if(occurance >= 3 && prev != number[i])
    deletePos.push({occurance: occurance, index:i});
  occurance = (prev == number[i]) ? (occurance + 1) : 1;
  prev = number[i];
}
/* Delete items in each positions. */
for(j = 0; j < deletePos.length; j++){
  var reObj = deletePos[j];
  number.splice((reObj.index - offset - reObj.occurance), reObj.occurance);
  offset += reObj.occurance;
}
document.write(number);
```

Comment: They aren't looking for duplicates, they are looking for 3-in-a-row. This would remove if there were just 2-in-a-row also.

Comment: no, my array contain a lot of duplicates. I do not want to use unique value from duplicates.

Comment: @s.purpose Without making the code too complicated, add `number = number.filter(function(item, pos, arr){
  return pos === 0 || item !== arr[pos-1];
});` after the last for loop. This will remove duplicates of any consecutive pairs.

Comment: @Rejith the code you added filters and removes duplicates. but this time I'm interested in the numbers in sequence that occurs only 2 times. which are 11,11 13,13 17,17. I want to grab them and put them in a new array called real=[]; so if everything works correctly. real will print out 11,13,17 only

Answer (score 0):

> I want to remove all numbers that repeats 2 or 3 times.

The parameters for [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) are

1. The starting index
2. The number of elements to delete starting at that index
3. Elements to add to the array (optional)

Your code should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    if (number[i] == number[i + 1])
        if (number[i] == number[i + 2])
            number.splice(i, 3);
        else
            number.splice(i, 2);
}
```

If you would like a more dynamic way of removing repeats (even more than 3), use an inner loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    var inARow = 1;
    while (number[i] == number[i + inARow])
        inARow++;
    if (inARow > 1)
        number.splice(i, inARow);
}
```

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pko3rrss/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @4castle

Comment: You're welcome. It's much less complicated than the other answers here, and has the correct output (if you look at the JSFiddle). Does it make sense to you?

Comment: what in the case if repeated numbers are not in sequence?

Comment: @KrupeshKotecha The OP only wants to remove them if they are in sequence. It's not obvious from the question, but they left several comments on different answers that said so. It's just that those answers were deleted for being wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var number = [11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 143, 143, 143, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 187, 187, 187, 191],
    isDuplicate = false,
    totalDuplicate = 0,
    thresHoldDuplicating = 3,
    tmpNumber = number[0],
    resultNumber = [tmpNumber];

var resetFn = function () {
    isDuplicate = false;
    totalDuplicate = 0;
}
for (i = 1; i < number.length; i++) {
    if (tmpNumber !== number[i]) {
        tmpNumber = number[i];
        resetFn();
        resultNumber.push(number[i]);
        continue;
    }

    isDuplicate = true;
    totalDuplicate += 1;
    
    if (totalDuplicate === thresHoldDuplicating - 1) {
        resetFn();
        resultNumber.splice((resultNumber.length - 1), thresHoldDuplicating);
    }
};
document.write('before: ' + number + '\n');
document.write('after: ' + resultNumber);
```

The idea is identify how many duplicate number in sequence. if it duplicate 3 times then remove the duplicated number from the Array.

Comment: it's not working accurately. your code is skipping some unique numbers. But the problem is the repetitive numbers. There are the ones I don't want to see in my array.

Comment: ah..
just update the code. I change resultNumber.splice((resultNumber.length - 2), thresHoldDuplicating);  to be resultNumber.splice((resultNumber.length - 1), thresHoldDuplicating);  on line #25

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var number = [11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 143, 143, 143, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 187, 187, 187, 191,319,319,319,323,323,323];
for (i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
  var cnt = 1,t = i,k = 0;
  while (number.indexOf(number[i], t==number.length-1?t:t + 1) >= 0 && k < number.length) {
    cnt++;
    var t = number.indexOf(number[i], t + 1);
    k++;
  }
  if (cnt >= 3) {
    var f = number[i];
    console.log("deleted " + f)
    while (number.indexOf(f) >= 0) {
      number.splice(number.indexOf(f), 1);
    }
  }
};
document.write(number);
```

Comment: There are a lot duplicates in my array. I added 319,319,319,323,323,323 at the end of the array to show that the code does not work in this case. If there is any duplicate usually there are 3 duplicates displayed consecutively. I want to remove all the 03.

Comment: i have updated my code. now its working in all the conditions